# Should I refrain from encoding information in the id attribute

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Lately I have gotten into the habit of encoding certain information in my ids. For instance, querying the database

```
select article_id, title from articles order by ...
```

and then using PHP to encode the information in the id of an element

```
foreach($article as $id=>$title){
    echo '<span class="title" id="a_'.$id.'">'.$title.'</span><br />';
}
```

I do this so that I can use javascript/jQuery to grab the id for an ajax call, say to fetch a preview or something

```
$("span.title").click(function(){
    var idArr = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    data = {};
    data.id = idArr[1];
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
});
```

I have never seen this method advocated, so I am beginning to wonder if I am setting myself up for some kind of catastrophe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using HTML5 you can use the data attribute.

e.g.

```
<span class="title" data-id="' . $id . '">'.$title.'</span>
```

Then you can access it via jQuery like this:

```
$("span.title").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Any browser compatibility issues?

Comment: For anyone interested, the note below the table is the answer to the question.